# Setting custom git config file location

Tags: git

I'm using Linux (Tcsh) and I'm trying to set a custom file that will not be in the home directory that will be accessed by the following command:

```
git config --global user.name <user-name>
```

It is in a script that I cannot modify.

I'm trying to do it without changing the environment variable `$HOME`. In other words, something like:

```
touch mygitconfigfile
./my-script-i-cant-edit
cat mygitconfigfile #has user.name config line
```

Is it possible?

Comment: If you just need the output, redirect `git config whatever >somefile`

Answer (score 1):

If you want `git config` to use a different file than e.g. `~/.gitconfig` (with `--global`), use the `--file` flag.

```
git config --file=/path/to/my-git-config-file user.name Robert
```

Consider `man git-config` for details.

Comment: Is it possible with an env variable?

Comment: @vesii What will be in the env variable?

Comment: the path to the file? I'm running a wrapper which executes `git config`.

Comment: @vesii So *you* are not executing `git config`? If no, you should clarify that in your question. Exactly what command does that wrapper execute?

Comment: Some script that just executes `git config --global user.name <user-name>`. I can't modify the command only set env variables

Comment: @vesii If the script executes just that and you can't change it, then you will have to mess around with the `$HOME` environment variable (as you have mentioned in the question) — if that works at all. I would consider changing the script somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Execute

```
git config --edit --global
```

And add the lines

```
[include]
    path = ~/someotherfile
```

Comment: Is it possible with an environment variable?

Comment: I looked at the comments and edits to your question and its unclear exactly what you need to do. What do you mean by the output?

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear. I have a script that runs the git-config command. I can't edit it but I would like to set the location of the file (instead of `$HOME` without changing `$HOME`). Is there some variable that I can set so it will force the git-config to use this location?

Comment: Try man git-config, but I’d doubt it. Why cant you edit the script? Further, why cant you run the commands yourself?